# How can a App read a file from my Cache directory?

Tags: android

I have a `file:///` `Uri`(image) that I am sending to other App's Activity for reading. This `Uri` is present in my cache directory like this:

```
file:///data/user/0/com.example/cache/temp1510385678660-359616374.jpg
```

The third party App(Gallery App in this case) shows a Toast *"Could not load media"* meaning it couldn't read the provided `Uri`.

I have added the following flags to the Intent:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Why is the other App not able to read my Uri and how can I make my Uri accessible?

---

Note: If you think, I should be using a `FileProvider`, I am actually using it for API >= 24 because using it on API < 24 leads to an error while sending the Uri to Google Photos App(a bug in their App).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is private internal storage for your app. So no other app has access.

You have to use a file provider.

Even if you place the file on external storage then on Android 7+ you need to use a file provider.